# Proof of expectation of exponential distribution

Tags: integration, statistics, limits-without-lhopital

I need help with understanding the proof of expectation of exponential distribution:

$$\begin{align}
E(X) & = \int_0^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx\\
& = [-xe^{-\lambda x}]_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}dx\\
& = (0-0) + [-\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}]_0^\infty\\
& = 0 + \left(0 + \frac{1}{\lambda}\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{\lambda}\\
\end{align}$$

I found myself having problems with substituting the limits into $[-xe^{-\lambda x}]$. It probably doesn't make sense using l'hopital's rule here, but I tried anyway, and ended up with $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$ instead of $0$.

Could any kind soul please show me how to substitute the limits? Thank you!

Comment: You "ended up with $\frac 1 \lambda$", that's correct, what's the problem?

Comment: I got $ \frac{1}{\lambda} $ from the substitution, and that meant ultimately I'll get $ \frac{2}{\lambda} $

Comment: Why? Perhaps you're not substituting *both* bounds? You need to do $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to +\infty}F(b) - F(0)$

Comment: Well yes, but I didn't understand how to substitute either bound. But I think Saphrosit explained it to me already. My problem was that I used l'hopital on both limits, when I can only use it for the part where x tended to infinity. When x=0, I don't need l'hopital to derive anything. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying de l'Hopital you get

$ \frac{-1}{\lambda \cdot e^{\lambda x}} $

which goes to $0$. You need to pay attention to the derivative of the exponential.

Comment: But wouldn't it be $ 0 - \frac{-1}{-\lambda \cdot e^{-\0}} $?

Comment: The second case is not of the type $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so you cannot apply De L'Hopital's rule, it simply makes $0$ as $e^{\lambda x} \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: @Saphrosit You have a sign error.

Comment: @GFauxPas it goes to $1$ anyway :p

Comment: @Saphrosit No it doesn't! Look carefully.

Comment: @Saphrosit THANKS SAPHROSIT! Silly me, when x=0, I simply get $[-0 *e^{0} = 0]$. There's no need for l'hopital on that one.

Comment: @GFauxPas are you talking about the answer or the comment? in the comment the limit is for $x \rightarrow 0$, so yes, it goes to $1$ both with $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$.

Comment: @Saphrosit $\dfrac {-1}{-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}} \to +\infty \text{ as } x \to +\infty$ because $\lambda > 0$

Comment: @GFauxPas Oh yes, sorry I thought you were talking about the comment! Fixed